# proving program equivalence

Tags: logic, formal-methods, hoare-logic

I understand that the general problem of program equivalence is undecidable, but I'm wondering what approaches exist to tackle the problem? I am familiar with Hoare-style verification, but are there any other frameworks for proving program equivalence?

Comment: This is a pretty general question: in general program verification is *domain specific*: you're trying to verify *something in particular*, e.g. safety or security, or the programs themselves are in a very constrained language. Do you have use-cases in mind? Are you trying to verify full functional equivalence? Something even stronger?

Answer (score 1):

One general approach to the problem is to prove program equivalence by showing the programs have the same semantics. Hoare-style verification, as you say, is one option categorized as [axiomatic semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiomatic_semantics). Have a look at [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) which describes most of the semantic approaches out there, including [denotational semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotational_semantics) and [operational semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_semantics).

Answer (score 0):

Proving this via a detour to a semantics is unnecessary and cumbersome.

Hoare logic is for showing that correctness conditions (AKA Hoare triples) of the form $\{\phi\}P\{\psi\}$ hold. To show equivalence of $P$ and $Q$, you'd have to show that
$$\{\phi\}P\{\psi\}$\quad\text{iff}\quad\{\phi\}Q\{\psi\}$$
for *all* pairs $(\phi,\psi)$ of pre- and postconditions. You could attempt that using a symbolic postcondition and then compare the two weakest preconditions. Dijkstra showed how to do that in the 70ies.

A more modern way of doing the same thing would be to use a *refinement calculus* to show that the two programs under consideration mutually refine each other. Consult any of the good books on the topic, e.g., Carroll Morgan's [Programming from Specifications](http://web.comlab.ox.ac.uk/oucl/publications/books/PfS/).

Comment: How is proving the equivalence of two programs by comparing their semantics a “detour”? Syntactic methods are rarely sufficient except to prove minor program transformations (such as many transformations done by compilers and optimizers).

Comment: What do you mean by "rarely sufficient". These methods are relatively complete (in the sense of Cook).